# DataGridTemplateColumn fire command on textChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Hello I am trying to fire and command time someone changes the text in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. When I use what is below it doesnt fire the command.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Booth">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Booth,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                            NotifyOnValidationError=False}">

                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
                                       TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                            Value="0" />
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Booth,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                            NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" 
                                       TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I didn't paste the entire DataGrid on here as it is pretty long, but here is opening tag.

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

I have tried to google this and could not find the it looks like others have used a Text_Changed event. I could not get this to fire either.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is the `Command` in the `Project` class implemented? because i think your `DataContext` at this point is the `Project` not the class where the `projects` are located. So you have to change the `DataContext`.

Comment: My DataContext is the ViewModel. that is where all the ObserveableColection<ProjectWrapper> is. I can post the ProjectWrapper and the ViewModel if that will help??

Comment: Yeah this is the `DataContext` for the `DataGrid` but i don't think that it is for the `Template` can you copy the command into the `ProjectWrapper` and make a dummy method for testing if this is fired?